# Type 'x' is not assignable to type 'x'. ts(2322)

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I have this in `@/components/ui/billboard.tsx` file

```js
import { Billboard } from "@/types"

interface BillboardProps {
    data: Billboard;
};

const Billboard: React.FC<BillboardProps> = ({
    data
    }) => { 
        console
    return (
        <div>{data.label}</div>
    )
}

export default Billboard;
```

and this it he type definition of a Billboard and Category in `@/types`file

```js
export interface Billboard {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    imageUrl: string
}
export interface Category {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    billboard: string;
}
```

and this in `@/app/routes/category/[categoryId]/page.tsx` file

```js
import Billboard from "@/components/ui/billboard";
import getCategory from "@/actions/get-category";

interface CategoryPageProps {
      // values
}

const CategoryPage: React.FC<CategoryPageProps> = async ({
params,
    searchParams
}) => {
const category = await getCategory(params.categoryId)
return (
        <Billboard data={category.billboard} /> // ⚠️ <-- error pops up here in the word data
      )
}
export default CategoryPage;
```

this is the getCategory component in `@/actions/get-category`

```js
import { Category } from "@/types";

const URL = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/categories`;

const getCategory = async (id: string): Promise<Category> => {
    const res = await fetch (`${URL}/${id}`);

    return res.json();
};

export default getCategory;
```

this is the error highlights on the data prop in `@/app/routes/category/[categoryId]/page.tsx` file. the code works properly and components are rendering but i have the error only highglighted on the vscode

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Billboard'.ts(2322)
billboard.tsx(4, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & BillboardProps'
(property) BillboardProps.data: Billboard
```

Comment: Looks like `await getCategory()` returns something like `{ billboard: string }`. What type does `category` have?

Comment: I've added the getCategory file

Comment: `<Billboard data={category.billboard} />` well you pass a value which is a string. And `React.FC<BillboardProps>`  clearly expects `BillboardProps` which is `{ data: Billboard; }`. I don't really see how the code can work properly given that you have a type mismatch and pass a string where something completely different is expected. IMO, the code *doesn't* work properly but just doesn't raise an error at runtime. Since you use `<div>{data.label}</div>` that should be taking the `label` property off of a string. Since that doesn't exist, you should be seeing `undefined`.

Comment: You're right man, I'm just a beginner in the typescript world thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Category` interface declaration is wrong. `Category["billboard"]` is of type `string` but should be of type `Billboard` instead.

```
export interface Category {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    billboard: string; // <- change this to 'Billboard'
}
```